# to generate pdf download using tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

i am not able to generate pdf download,my code is as follows,can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code.

```
include 'tcpdf.php';
$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
$html = '<html>
<head></head>
<body><table border="1">
<tr><th>name</th>
<th>company</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>hello</td>
<td>xx technologies</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: Have you any errors that PHP reports ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have modified your code and it works. **[TESTED]**

```
<?php
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);
$pdf->AddPage();
$html = '<html>
<head></head>
<body><table border="1">
<tr><th>name</th>
<th>company</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>hello</td>
<td>xx technologies</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('htmlout.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: hi shankar,still m not getting the output

Comment: Hi Namratha, its working as charm. Can you describe the error ? Is your tcpdf libraries are properly being referenced ?

Comment: i am trying to do it, but it shows TCPDF class not found, but i have added all the files.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make the file downloads, use PHP function `header` before your `$pdf->Output();` like this :

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
$pdf->Output(); # terminate your file with TCPDF output
```

See [PHP function header](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php) on php.net

Comment: not at all, this answer is not correct, tcpdf class provide methods natively, just pass this argument the Output method:
$pdf->Output('yourfilename.pdf', 'D');
that's all

Answer (score 3):

Add this line `$pdf->Output($downlaodname, 'D');` instead of `$pdf->Output();`. It will force browser to download file.

Comment: This answer works on Chrome and my environment