# Chrome error when generating PDF with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, http-headers, tcpdf

I am having an issue displaying PDF with PHP in chrome.

### Context:

I'm using TCPDF (http://www.tcpdf.org/) to generate a PDF.
I set my header like this :

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="Sujet.pdf"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
```

In a testing purpose, I have placed my headers at the very beginning of my index.php file, just after first `<?php`

Other info, i'm using the FatFree Framework, I don't think headers are handled by the framework.

And I'm displaying PDF using an extension of TCPDF class. I have made an extended class implementing the function `render` which uses the following command :

```
$this->Output('Sujet.pdf', 'I');
```

### Problem :

1. With chrome : PDF won't display, I'm having a `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE`.
2. With firefox : The PDF is displayed but there is a firebug error : `NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error`. Answer is

> the resource from this url is not text

I think it means that firefox expected text and had something else instead.

Also, PDF are correctly displayed on the TCPDF website examples. In my opinion, the problem comes from wrong or misplaced headers.

Thank you for considering my issue.

Matthias

Comment: can you post your full code

Comment: index.php or the tcpdf class ? both ? What do you think is relevant ?

Comment: As a response it says that firefox expected text but got something else.

Answer (score 1):

use header function

`public function Header()`

Comment: Are you speaking of TCPDF header function ?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Headers are taken into charge by TCPDF, they wasn't needed here. But it wasn't the issue.

It came from a line that had no point being there:

```
echo \Template::instance()->render($pdf->rendu($f3, $this));
```

This was line came from the time I was trying to use FatFree Templates to write html with TCPDF. Forgot to erase it.

Answer (score -1):

The `index.php` file :

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="Sujet.pdf"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

// defining constants
include('liste_permissions.php');
define('PAGE_ERREUR', 'templates/forbidden.htm');

// adding librairies
$f3 = require('lib/base.php');
// adding config files
$f3->config('config/config.ini');
$f3->config('config/routes.ini');
$f3->config('config/bdd.ini');

// defining other constants in the Hive of fatfree framework
$bdd = new Bdd($f3);
$f3->set('Bdd', $bdd->getDb());
$f3->set('f3', $f3);
$f3->set('FILE', __FILE__);

// Global functions used a lot
include('fct_globales.php');

// Refreshing the session of the connexion
\Membre\Manager::instance()->refreshConnection();

// running fatfree framework
$f3->run();
```

The routing service calls the following function :

```
function renduPdf($f3) {

    if(CIA(SEE_SUJETS_ET_COR)) {
        $pdf = new \Pdf;
        $pdf->rendu(Manager::instance()->getFromId($f3->get('PARAMS.id')));
        echo \Template::instance()->render($pdf->rendu($f3, $this));
    }
    else {
        echo ERREUR;
    }
}
```

and `pdf->rendu()` is here : (pdf extends TCPDF class)

```
public function rendu(\Sujet\Data $sujet) {
    //fatfree base
    $f3 = \Base::instance();
    // Setting the class attributes
    $this->sujet = $sujet;
    $questions = $sujet->getQuestions();
    $this->nomAbrege = 'CB' . $sujet->getNumero_cb();
    $this->numMatiere = $sujet->getMatiere();
    $this->nomMatiere = $f3->get('matieres')[$sujet->getMatiere()];

    // PDF initialisation : author, imagescale
    $this->initialisation();

    // Displaying questions
    $this->premierePage();
    foreach ($questions as $question) {
        $this->question($question);
    }

    $this->Output('Sujet.pdf', 'I');
}
```

Comment: generate and render a PDF with PHP

Comment: and how should i go ?

Comment: Follow that link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223743/to-generate-pdf-download-using-tcpdf