# How to disable 'Save changes' dialog in Adobe Reader (create PDF using TCPDF)?

Tags: tcpdf, savechanges, adobe-reader

We are using TCPDF library to generate the PDF file from HTML. It is working fine in Web Brower but when we open and then close it in Adobe Reader it is showing a dialog **Do you want to Save Changes xyz file**. Visited different forums but can't find the solution to fix this.

Comment: Please read this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223743/to-generate-pdf-download-using-tcpdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must echo the output function because it returns a string so you should echo that output function as well.

Please see the code snippet below:

```
$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'D');
echo $pdf->Output;
```

Or you can try this too:

```
$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'D');
exit();
```